# Syncfusion Blazor: Binding drop-down list in Grid column

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, syncfusion

I am using Syncfusion Grid in a **Blazor Core 3.1.0 App**. I am binding data through a **Web API**. Now I want to show a dropdown list in one of the columns.

By this URL:

> *Api/Default/GetProjectsList*

I get the key and value pair that I need to bind to the drop-down list's *text* and *value*.

I have used the *EjsDropDownList* control and bound the data with the list. But how to show this list as a column in the Grid is where I am struggling at. Tried enclosing it in a `<GridColumn>` tag but the list has not become a part of the Grid.

```
<EjsGrid TValue="Order" AllowPaging="true" Toolbar="@(new List<string>() { "Add", "Edit", "Delete", "Cancel", "Update" })">
   <EjsDataManager Url="/Api/Orders" Adaptor="Adaptors.WebApiAdaptor"></EjsDataManager>
     <GridEditSettings AllowAdding="true" AllowDeleting="true" AllowEditing="true" Mode="EditMode.Normal"></GridEditSettings>
       <GridColumns>

          <GridColumn>
                  <EjsDropDownList TValue="string" Placeholder="Select a Project">
                        <EjsDataManager Url="/Api/Default/GetProjectsList" Adaptor="Adaptors.WebApiAdaptor" CrossDomain=true></EjsDataManager>
                        <DropDownListFieldSettings Text="Item1" Value="Item2"></DropDownListFieldSettings>
                  </EjsDropDownList>  
          </GridColumn>

          <GridColumn Field=@nameof(Order.OrderId) DefaultValue="0" IsIdentity="true" IsPrimaryKey="true" HeaderText="ID" TextAlign="TextAlign.Right">
          </GridColumn> 

    </GridColumns>
    </EjsGrid>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the **“Column Template feature”** of Grid. With this you can display a Dropdown bound with List in a Grid’s column. Please refer the documentation link below,

Documentation : 
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/blazor/documentation/grid/columns/?no-cache=1#column-template
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/blazor/documentation/grid/templates/

Please use the code below,

```
    <EjsGrid TValue="Order" ModelType="@Model" AllowPaging="true" ...>
    ...
   <GridColumns>
        <GridColumn>
            <Template>
                <EjsDropDownList TValue="string" Placeholder="Select a Project">
                    <EjsDataManager Url="/Api/Default/GetProjectsList" Adaptor="Adaptors.WebApiAdaptor" CrossDomain=true></EjsDataManager>
                    <DropDownListFieldSettings Text="Item1" Value="Item2"></DropDownListFieldSettings>
                </EjsDropDownList>
            </Template>
        </GridColumn>
        ...
    </GridColumns>
</EjsGrid>

@code{

    EjsButton accountButton;
    public Order Model = new Order();
    ...
}
```

And also if you want to display the DropDown when perform editing in Grid. Then set the **“EditType”** for the column as **“DropDownEdit”** or you can also use the **“Edit Template feature”**. Please refer the below documentations for more details regarding this,

Documentations : 
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/blazor/documentation/grid/editing/#cell-edit-type-and-its-params
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/blazor/documentation/grid/editing/#cell-edit-template

Comment: I am not able to understand how the Model will be populated. Can you please guide me?

Comment: I followed these instructions and got the following error: "The child content element 'Template' of component 'GridColumn' uses the same parameter name ('context') as enclosing child content element 'Authorized' of component 'AuthorizeView'. Specify the parameter name like: '<Template Context="another_name"> to resolve the ambiguity(RZ9999)"